# How to compare Val function with "" in Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am taking a user input a text box and then Validating it as follows:

```
Val(txt_score1.text)
```

Then I have to compare it with blank entry in that text box. Like this:

```
If (Val(txt_score1.Text) = "") Then....
```

I am receiving a conversion error. Because "" is String whereas Val is returning Integer.

How to overcome this??

Comment: Difficult to give you an answer that will actually help you without knowing what you want to test for. What are you trying to check there, exactly?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the purpose of the `Val` function. As the error message you are getting is telling you, `Val` takes a string argument and tries to convert it to an integer. It has been a part of the BASIC language for a long time. If you could explain precisely what kind of validation you want to carry out on the text, people could help more

Comment: I think you are looking for [IsNumeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6cd3f6w1(v=vs.90).aspx) function.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Integer.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) to determine if the value is a proper integer:

```
    Dim x As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, x) Then
        MessageBox.Show(x)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("'" + TextBox1.Text + "' is not a valid number")
    End If
```

If you need to just check for a blank string, you can use [String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) on the text itself:

```
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("String is empty")
    End If
```

`Val` is a legacy function leftover from VB6 days and has some weird behavior if you don't know about it.  I avoid it for this reason. For example, take the following cases and the output they generate:

```
    MessageBox.Show(Val(""))        '0
    MessageBox.Show(Val("5"))       '5
    MessageBox.Show(Val("5e3"))     '5000
    MessageBox.Show(Val("5xyz"))    '5
```